# Hip hop instrumental track used on "Freerunning Bangkok's Ghost Tower" video

Tags: identify-this-song, instrumental, hip-hop

I've been looking for title of this song / music, but have had no luck.  It is used in the "Freerunning Bangkok's Ghost Tower" video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYUxHhF0LZk&t=118s

Comment: Shazam pointed me at "Foxes On Point" by Gangsta Animals, but that song seems to use that background track with the group rapping over it, so it's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: @JoeKennedy - it could be the instrumental version of the song...

Comment: @ChrisSunami that's true, but to me it seems like the artist is sampling it. Check it out on [their site](http://www.gangstaanimals.com/music). It starts playing automatically when you go to the site (or at least it does for me). Their site doesn't seem to have any instrumental versions of their songs, and also the quality of the vocal track seems to be kind of low compared to the instrumental track. It sounds like Gangsta Animals just found the song somewhere and then recorded their vocals on a laptop over the track.

Answer (score 2):

This song is from the music Library [Epidemic Sound](http://www.epidemicsound.com/) and is called [*Big Plans*](https://player.epidemicsound.com/search/?search_query=Jan%20Chmelar%20Big%20Plans), by **Jan Chmelar**.

The genre is 2000s Hip Hops and the tag is "Chasing", with 100 bpm and "High" energy, so it fits well the video.

Alternative [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHjjkN-Q1as).